# Big numbers calculations in Java?

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger

I have this Java code for computing some numbers

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Challenge {

    final static BigInteger THOUSAND = new BigInteger("1000");

    private static BigInteger compute(long n) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            BigInteger next = b.multiply(b).add(a);
            a = b;
            b = next;
        }
        return b.mod(THOUSAND);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (long n : new long[] { 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 20L, Long.MAX_VALUE }) {
            System.out.print(n + " ---> ");
            System.out.println(compute(n));
        }
    }
}
```

The code iterates several times according to given long numbers (1, 2, 5, etc), starting with `a=1` and `b=1`:

```
next = (b*b)+a
a = b
b = next
```

It then returns `b mod 1000`, which it gives the last 3 digits of the calculation.

So far the codes returns:

```
1 ---> 2
2 ---> 5
5 ---> 783
10 ---> 968
20 ---> 351
9223372036854775807 --->
```

On the last one the code keeps working but the number if iterations is so big it takes forever so it never finishes.

Is there a way to do this kind of calculations faster, or to get the desired value (mod 1000 of the calculation done that many times) in a better way?

Comment: Does it really need to work for `Long.MAX_VALUE`? If so, forget about the `for` loop, there's no way you can loop 9223372036854775807 times.

Comment: Since you're doing the `mod 1000` in the end, you may as well scrap the `BigInteger` and do it all in ints by moding with 1k every iteration. Also, you're *obviously* required to find the period of the sequence. There's no way anyone sane would ask you to loop `Long.MAX_VALUE` times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be a lot faster if you use an `int` for your calculations.  However you will get a better speed up from realising that in each iteration there is only 1,000,000 possible starting values for `a` and `b` which means the longest possible sequence of values and results for `a` and `b` without repeating is one million. i.e. you can `n % 1,000,000` Most likely there is a shorter repeating sequences.

The reason I say only the lower three digits of `a` and `b` matter is that you `mod 1000` the result, so not matter what the upper digits of `a` and `b` are they are ignored so all you care about are the values `0` to `999`

You can memorizes all possible results starting at 1,1 and it will just be a lookup.

```
private static long compute(long n) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    for (int i = 0, max = (int) (n % 1000000); i < max; i++) {
        int next = b * b + a;
        a = b;
        b = next % 1000;
    }
    return b % 1000;
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, what I need to do then is iterate until `i < max`, instead of `i < n`, right? I changed that and it seems to work fine, and the number is 512. Although I still don't entirely understand why there's only 1,000,000 possible starting values for a and b.

Comment: Is 1,000,000 the period of the function?

Comment: @Julian only the lower 3 digits of `a` and `b` matter.  The longest possible sequence of these includes every possible combination of 1000 * 1000.  It is possible the repeating sequence is shorter though it should be a factor of 1000000.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, keep the running moludo for each calculation. You don't need to calculate all the digits since you are only interested in the last 3 ones.

A first improvement is to have the following:

```
private static BigInteger compute(long n) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        BigInteger next = b.multiply(b).add(a);
        a = b;
        b = next.mod(THOUSAND); // <-- only keep the modulo each time so as not calculate all digits
    }
    return b.mod(THOUSAND);
}
```

By doing this, you can realize that you don't need `BigInteger`  to begin with. The numbers concerned become of value low enough that they hold into a primitive datatype. As such, use a `long` (or even an `int`): it will be a lot more performant since you don't have the overhead of using a `BigInteger`.

```
private static long compute(long n) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int next = b*b + a;
        a = b;
        b = next % 1000;
    }
    return b % 1000;
}
```

Note that this code still won't give you the result for `9223372036854775807` as input. It is simply not possible to loop `9223372036854775807` times. However, this produces the correct result for 100 million in under 5 seconds on my old machine.

Answer (score -3):

The number is to big. It's normal to take so long to process this function.
You can try to check using this:

`long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    .....your program....
    long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(totalTime);`

the estimate time to finish it.